# Почему при ключевом слове await перестает работать try/catch, и компилятор не выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient

Вот код, при отправке `post` запроса с `await`. `try/cathc` перестает работать, и если убрать try/catch, то компилятор все равно пропустит ошибку, и не остановится даже.

```
using (var HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
     try
     {
        var data = new StringContent("langid=5&pagename=index&pid=5&typo=avail", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://www.platek.eu/templates/inc/ajaxcore.php?ajaxCmd=getProductColors", data);
        string result = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json_Response2.Temperatures>(result);

        foreach (var color in json.Datax)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(color.Title);
          var colore += Regex.Replace(color.Title, @"\s+", " ") + ";\r\n";
        }
     }catch(Exception sd)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(sd);
     }
}
```

Даже если ставить `try/catch` в любом другом месте, даже за using, ошибка не отлавливается.
Но если убрать `await`, все работает нормально

Json код:

```
class Json_Response2
    {
        public partial class Temperatures
        {

            [JsonProperty("datax")]
            public Datax[] Datax { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Datax
        {
            [JsonProperty("title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ral")]
            public object Ral { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("codex")]
            public string Codex { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("img")]
            public string Img { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `awaut HttpClient.PostAsync`

Comment: Кусок кода, который вы показали, синтаксически некорректен. Он в принципе не компилируется. Отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комбинация из `.Result` и `var` сбила вас с толку. Постарайтесь запомнить, что для незавершенного `Task` не следует вызывать `.Result`, а вместо этого использовать `await`.

```cs
var fromData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["langid"] = "5" 
    ["pagename"] = "index",
    ["pid"] = "5",
    ["typo"] = "avail"
};
var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
using HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.PostAsync("https://www.platek.eu/templates/inc/ajaxcore.php?ajaxCmd=getProductColors", data);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Ни одного `.Result` здесь быть не должно.

> Как узнать когда `Task` завершился?

На примере последней строчки

```cs
Task<string> resultTask = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
string result;
if (resultTask.IsCompleted)
    result = resultTask.Result;
else
    result = await resultTask;
```

Но в этой проверке нет особого смысла, проще сразу написать `await` и не думать об этом. `await` можно использовать и для завершенных и для незавершенных задач.

Comment: Как узнать когда Task завершился?

Comment: @PrinceTag дополнил ответ. Вы бы лучше поравили код в вопросе, ну так чтобы он компилировался, да и отформатировать его с нормальными отступами не помешало. Это все-таки база знаний, а не форум, на котором запостил и забыл. Ну или хотя-бы примите ответ галочкой, если считаете его полезным